# Not work createWriteStream and absolute path

Tags: node.js, fs

I have 1 issue. Don't understand how it works.

I want create file within `fs.createWriteStream` and so works only with relative path. All folders was created

```js
let p = path.resolve(`../uploads/${data.id}/${file.originalname}`).toString()

outStream = fs.createWriteStream(`./uploads/example.txt`,{flags:'w'}) //work
outStream = fs.createWriteStream(`${__dirname}/uploads/2/example.txt`,{flags:'w'}) //not work

outStream = fs.createWriteStream(p,{flags:'w'}) //not work
```

ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/arsenkarapetan/Documents/sedalina/server/uploads/2/example.txt'

How it do correct? Maybe i don't have permission?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The directory `/Users/arsenkarapetan/Documents/sedalina/server/uploads/2/` needs to exist before you can create a file in it, and I think that it might not yet exist in your situation.

You can use a module like [`mkdirp`](https://github.com/substack/node-mkdirp) to first create all the intermediate directories before creating the file stream.

Comment: Another reason could be, not to use a system path delimiter in the file name :)